# Creating a class to throw in case of error

Tags: class, c++11, vector, throw

I have created my own vector class that behaves somewhat like the usual std::vector (I needed to do this for this assignment). Now I want to make sure that if someone tries to write something into this vector class that is out of range of the memory it has access to, it gives an error and terminates the program.

My attempt:

```
template<typename T>
class vector
{
    private:
        T *elements;
        int sz;

    public:
        // vector functions etc. //
        struct out_of_range
        {
            string s;
            out_of_range(string b) : s{b} {cerr << "error: " << s << endl;}
        };
};
```

So now in my vector member functions that can run into an out of range error, i throw this class. For example in my operator overloading of [], I have a check like this:

```
if(i < 0 || sz <= i) throw out_of_range("index out of range");
```

Now this works, and terminates the program with the following message:

> error: index is out of range
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'vector::out_of_range'
>   Aborted (core dumped)

My question is if this is the correct approach. Am I allowed to cerr from a function like I have and can I simply throw this function without catching it? As far as I'm aware, throwing without catching calls terminate() right? Is this bad coding practice?

I hope I haven't confused you guys and that my question is somewhat understandable. Thanks for any help in advance :)

edit: sorry I should have mentioned, I am not permitted to use any classes I have not created myself except for some basic ones like std::string and the basic inputs and outputs.

Comment: How about reusing [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range)? Or using/inheriting one of the other standard exception classes (documented [in e.g. this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error))?

Comment: I guess the point here is not reuse (because so the whole vector component should be reused) but learn about write data structures.

Comment: @Doleron you are absolutely correct and I have edited the post because I've forgotten to specify that. I need to create my own classes to use and can only use std::string and std::cout/cerr/cin.

Comment: Well if you can't use the standard exception classes, then how about using them for *reference*? Examine how they work, what happens when you use them, etc. Then emulate that interface and behavior in your own exception classes.

Comment: Would you happen to know of a resource that explains how they work? I struggle to find a website that lays the code bare and also explains why stuff does what it does. It makes it very hard for me to understand. I'm relatively new to c++ so I need something that explains things in detail/well, if you get what I mean.

Comment: One issue with this approach: `vector<int>::out_of_range`, `vector<SomeClass>::out_of_range`, and so on, are all different types. So code that wants to catch this type of exception can catch a specific type or maybe list a few specific types to catch, but there's no way to catch all `out_of_range` exceptions from any possible specialization of your `vector` template.

Answer (score 0):

Different of Java, in C++ you could use non-exception-specific elements to use in a throw statement. So, your struct is suitable to be used as expression parameter for throw an exception such that (just like an int number does).

However, since you are using an OOP approach to write your programs, you should also apply a class alternative for your exceptions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class myexception: public exception {

    virtual const char* what() const throw() {
        return "My exception happened";
    }
} myex;

int main () {

    try {
        throw myex;
    } catch (exception& e) {
        cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Taken from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/).

The first impression is that the both alternatives are equivalent. The benefit of the class based over the struct based is that with a class you can extract the benefits of reuse, extension, encapsulation and so on provided by the object oriented approach which can be valuable when programming more complex, huge and long life systems.